# Reset Windows 7 so its like the first time you login after an install

Tags: windows-7, windows

Ive seen someone reset Windows 7 after he used the computer for a while so that the next time it booted up it was just like it had been installed for the first time asking for users and timezone etc.

I think he ran a dos command that he ran but I am not 100%. Does anyone know of such a command on Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be the `sysprep` command. It's used by OEMs and corporate IT departments to prepare disk images. It most likely used the `/oobe` flag, which tells it to put the computer back to the "Out of box experience".

Answer (score 1):

[Sysprep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysprep)

And it wasn't a DOS command, the last edition of Windows that had a DOS subsystem was Windows ME. He ran it from the command line.